# iPython on Win8 fails to install modules

Tags: python-3.x, windows-8, jupyter-notebook

Please bear with me the total novice of Python 3 and non native English speaker.

I'm using windows 8 in iPython notebook environment, and I have problem installing modules such as [Jieba](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jieba/). If you go to its homepage, the English version is in the bottom (however, not as updated as the Chinese version). It says it supports Python 3 as well, so I tried using git as it suggested, but it gave me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp8N0.jpg) (I successfully cloned it before).

Some other things I tried as well

- Using cmd to run setup.py
- Using pip3 (it's another module I failed to install)
- Installing easy_install (same, couldn't install it)

Do I have to use other approaches to install modules cause I'm using iPython notebook? I'm so frustrated. I'm trying to do text mining on some Chinese texts but I struggle so much with this hurdle already.

Answer (score 1):

You've already cloned Jieba into your home directory (`~`), which is why your second attempt at cloning failed. Enter the `jieba` directory, and run `git pull` to sync any changes from the master repo. You can then run `python setup.py install` in that directory to install the module.

To install `pip` on Windows, follow the instructions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).